# XML or String function in Oracle

Tags: xml, oracle11g

I need to find a solution for the following. I have XML files stored in the one of the columns of my table and I need to extract only HASNumber from the same file with the following conditions.

If the   there are any file got `<Identification>` along with  `<Impurities>` or `<Additives>` then no `HASNumber`  selected.

If there are only `<Identification>` without impurities or additive tag the all the HASNumbers should be selected.

1) Don’t select HASNumber from the following condition

```
 <Identification><Impurities> <HASNumber>1113-22-1</HASNumber>
 <Identification> <'Additives> <HASNumber>1113-22-1</HASNumber>
```

2) Select HASNumber only from the following condition

```
<Identification> <HASNumber>1113-22-1</HASNumber>
```

Comment: read it from db and then do getElementsByTag() from the xmldocument..based on occurrences of the elements we can do..post some portion of xml which contains above two cases..Are you writing this using JAVA

Comment: I wanted to write an PLSQL script for this.